# How to unlock keychain when building Cordova app for iOS from Visal Studio 2015

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, build, keychain

We are using Cordova in Visual Studio 2015 to make a cross platform app. For android the app works.

When building for iOS with Visual Studio (connected to a MAC) it fails because the keychain is locked and we get the error

`SecKey API returned: -25308`

When logging into the MAC with putty and then unlocking the keychain with

`security unlock-keychain -p <pass> <keychain>`

and then execute the exact same command as seen in the build output from Visual Studio it works.

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign <sign> --entitlements <name>.app.xcent --timestamp=none <name>.app
```

How can we execute the “security unlock…” command during the build process started from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `unlock-keychain` command in the same terminal session before you start the remotebuild agent.

```
security unlock-keychain -p <pass> <keychain>
remotebuild
```

Comment: Thank's for pointing in the direction of remotebuild! Do you also know where/when the terminal session (where remotebuild starts) is started? Thats's a disadvantage of using Visual Studio. Ones presses a build button and then it's hard to follow what's happening in the background. I tried for days finding the right script/place but it is hard to find.

Comment: How did you set up your mac? Are you using steps like these https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/

Comment: It's hard to say because I never worked on a MAC before so everything is new. I followed this https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/ and then tried for days with all kind of options. The CLI command "remotebuild test --device" from your link gives an error "Error: taco-remote test failed"

Comment: Under section "Start the remote agent on your Mac", run the security unlock-keychain command right before running the remotebuild command

Comment: Thanks that is a good idea! Hopefully it cannot be locked again when e.g. starting the project in xcode In case of testing on the mac.

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked for me, when building an ionic 3 project on a mac